# Watir automation: how to select item from combo list

Tags: ruby, watir

I need to select one of the items from combo list. Could you help? In Development tool items declared as:

```
<div class="x-combo-list-inner" id="ext-gen146" style="width: 298px; height: 62px;">
    <div class="x-combo-list-item">Select..
    <div class="x-combo-list-item">Benefits Quick Case
    <div class="x-combo-list-item x-combo-selected">Time Off Quick Case</
</div>
```

Code:

`topic_dropdown_box.click`

`sleep 7`

`def combo_list_Timeoff.click`

`def combo_list_Timeoff; @browser.iframe(:class, 'ext-shim').div(:css, 'x-combo-list-item x-combo-selected').div(:text, 'Time Off Quick Case');end`

Comment: Above details from Development tool.

Comment: We'd like to see your code attempt toward solving this. Please see "[mcve]" and "[ask]".

Comment: Please update the html to include the iframe. Please add the test code you are using in a formatted fashion in this question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain I know what you are looking for here.
`#select_list` will only work on `select`/`option` html elements, so likely you will need to open the drop down before clicking the option you want.

Depending on how this is implemented in your application, you will likely need to do something along the lines of:

```
combo_list = @browser.div(id: "ext-gen146")
combo_list.click
combo_list.div(text: "Time Off Quick Case").when_present.click
```

It appears that 'ext-gen146' is dynamically generated, in which case you could do something like: `(id: /ext-gen\d\d\d/)`

UPDATE:
The `class` selector can only take one class as an argument. Try:

`@browser.iframe(class: 'ext-shim').div(css: '.x-combo-list-item.x-combo-selected').div(text: 'Time Off Quick Case')`

actually, so long as the text is present, you shouldn't even need the intermediary div:
`@browser.iframe(class: 'ext-shim').div(text: 'Time Off Quick Case')`

Comment: Thank you!  I am still researching how to do it.  I can open drop down. However cannot select items from drop down list, it does not have value only class.  If I use example above, have error undefined method `div' for #<Watir::DivCollection:0x2bf0110>   My script:               topic_box.click
   sleep 7
   quick_combo_list.div(text: "Benefits Quick Case").click

Comment: I updated the answer with `when_present` which should allow you to avoid the sleep. You only get a `DivCollection` when you use `divs` instead of `div`.

Comment: I have unsuccessful result.   Problem is I cannot declare and talk to "Time Off Quick Case".   In my scrip I open drop down box and cannot talk to x-combo-list-inner, instead I am trying to talk to Time Off Quick Case" directly.  I undusted your comments, Thank you!  However cannot use them because cannot talk to combo list and his items.

Comment: My script:                                                         `topic_dropdown_box.click`              `combo_list_Timeoff.when_present.click`                                                    `def combo_list_Timeoff; @browser.iframe(:class, 'ext-shim').div(:class, 'x-combo-list-item x-combo-selected').div(:text, 'Time Off Quick Case');end
`

Comment: Still not working.  Thank you so mush for support! I spent a lot of time for this object, I may just take this test case off.  Below error results :              until': timed out after 60 seconds (Watir::Wait::TimeoutError)
 `@browser.iframe(class: 'ext-shim').div(text: 'Time Off Quick Case').when_present.click`

Comment: assert_exists': Unable to locate element, using {:tag_name=>["div"], :text=>"Time Off Quick Case"} (Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException)
 `@browser.iframe(class: 'ext-shim').div(text: 'Time Off Quick Case').click`

Comment: Its working!  Thank you!!! I have several iframe in the code, I was using the first one(class: 'ext-shim').  I tried other iframe that listed in development tool and it worked.   `@browser.iframe(:name, 'askHR').div(text: 'Time Off Quick Case').click`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

[browser].select_list(:id, "[id tag]").select_value("[value to be selected]")

Comment: Please explain *why* this is appropriate.